# The difference between $[n]^k$ and $\begin{pmatrix} [n]\\ k \\\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

as the title suggests, I am not able to clearly distinguish between these 2 sets. 
To avoid confusion over notation, my notes define them as follows:

i) For any integer $r \ge 0$, the family $\{A\subseteq X:|A|=r \}$ of all r-element subsets of X is denoted by $\begin{pmatrix} X\\ r \\\end{pmatrix}$

ii) $X_1 \times X_2 \times ... \times X_k =  \{ (x_1,x_2,...,x_k) : x_1\in X_1, x_2 \in X_2, ..., x_k \in X_k \}$. If $X_1=X_2=...=X_k$ then $X_1 \times X_2 \times ... \times X_k$ is also denoted by $X^k$

So for $X=[n]$, $k=r$ what is stopping  $\begin{pmatrix} [n]\\ k \\\end{pmatrix}$ from being the same as $[n]^k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset only contains each element once, and is unordered: $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ are the same set, and $\{1,1,2\}$ is not a different set from $\{1,2\}$.

In contrast, $X \times Y$ is defined using *ordered* pairs (or ordered $k$-tuples if the product has $k$ sets in it). In the case that the sets are different, it is clear what this means: the first element must come from $X$, the second from $Y$, so if $X=\{1\}$ and $Y=\{\text{blue}\}$, then $ (1,\text{blue}) \in X \times Y $, but $(\text{blue},1) \notin X \times Y$. But even if the sets are the same, this means that each pair is different, even if the elements it contains are the same in a different order: $(1,2) \neq (2,1)$ (think of co-ordinates).

Comment: Thank you very much!
I've realized that one contain repetition and the other does not.

Answer (score 1):

A lot. $[2]^2$ contains $(1,1), (1,2),(2,1),$ and $(2,2)$, whereas $[2]\choose 2$ contains $\{1,2\}$ only.